# Django ORM Union как таблица для FROM

Tags: django, django-orm

Можно ли сделать через Django ORM запросы UNION по нескольким таблицам и потом результат использовать для FROM как общую таблицу.

Делал так `qs = q1.union(q2, q3, all=True)` но у `qs` нельзя уже дальше применять `filter`

Вот такой запрос должен быть в итоге:

```sql
SELECT
    m.id
    ,m.count
    ,m.tp__code
    ,sco.name AS name
FROM (
    SELECT branch_id as id, 'contracts' as tp__code, count(*) AS count FROM d_parts GROUP BY branch_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT branch_id as id, 'newparts' as tp__code, count(*) AS count FROM d_new_parts GROUP BY branch_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT branch_id as id, 'tires' as tp__code, count(*) AS count FROM d_tires GROUP BY branch_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT branch_id as id, 'wheels' as tp__code, count(*) AS count FROM d_wheels GROUP BY branch_id
) as m
INNER JOIN branch sbr ON sbr.branch_id = m.id
INNER JOIN company sco ON sco.company_id = sbr.company_id
```

Comment: Сделайте 4 отдельных запроса, а потом уже UNION. И, кстати, выполняться он будет быстрее.

Comment: @Akina нет, не быстрее, много JOIN идет и если делать отдельно то для каждой таблицы они происходят. Проверил на запросе, в 12 раз медленнее получается, вместо 1 сек в моем варианте, выходит 12 сек

Comment: Значит, у Вас частный случай, когда объединённая таблица помещается в памяти без материализации. Бывает и так...

Answer (score 0):

В частности для PostgreSQL удалось реализовать через [CREATE VIEW](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/13/sql-createview) и получаем в итоге обращение как к обычной таблице.

Просто делаем модель для этой таблицы и делаем запросы как обычно

```
class VPriceListBranchCounts(models.Model):  # CREATE VIEW
    part_types = models.JSONField(verbose_name='Типы товаров с количеством')
    branch = models.ForeignKey('company.Branch', models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Филиал', db_column='branch_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'v_price_list_branch_counts'
```

Так же можно воспользоваться модулем [django-database-view](https://pypi.org/project/django-database-view/) для создания этой модели, в нем выполняются миграции